# Zoom in/ zoom out within web-browser on windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser, zooming

I've built an example with web-browser in windows phone 7. When I load an html file which created by myself, I can double click on web-browser to zoom in/ zoom out the content. But, when I load an web-page (ex: google.com) I can't.
I uploaded my example to my skydriver account. You can't get it at http://cid-b65eb4d185de7cfc.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/Shared/Sandbox.WebBrowser.zip

If you known the reason why, please help me.

Comment: Are you wanting to control the zooming through code? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500062/wp7-webbrowser-control-zoom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason lies in the meta tags within the HTML headers from Google.

I'd guess that Google have fixed the viewport to not allow zooming:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
```

See this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/displaying-html-content-in-windows-phone-7.aspx