# How to call a jQuery function from .NET WebBrowser control using InvokeScript()?

Tags: jquery, webbrowser-control, invokescript

Had a Windows Forms app using a WebBrowser control (.NET 4) to load a web page that communicated with the app. I had a call to `InvokeScript()` to call a Javascript routine in the web page at one point.

Now things have been "updated", and jQuery is now being used. So instead of having a `OnVenueSelected()` function to call, it's now some `$.city.venue.onVenueSelected: function(param)` oddity.

Simply changing my call from `InvokeScript("OnVenueSelected", new object[] { params })` to `InvokeScript("$.city.venue.onVenueSelected", new object[] { params })` did not work. I don't get any observable errors or exceptions, but the logic in the call is not invoked.

Some digging around had me trying to use `eval` as the call and passing the function name and parameters as the string to `eval`. That didn't work either.

Is there a known way to invoke a function that's embedded in a couple of layers of jQuery magic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK - I get to answer my own question. Thanks in part to the answer by    at  [How to call a jQuery function from .NET WebBrowser control using InvokeScript()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188063/how-to-call-a-jquery-function-from-net-webbrowser-control-using-invokescript), I was able to change my call to the jQuery function to

```
string[] codeString = { String.Format(" {0}('{1}') ", @"$.city.venue.onVenueSelected", result.ToString()) };
this.myBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", codeString);
```

Amazingly enough, this seems to be working.

In my case, the result variable is of type `bool` (in case that matters to anyone).

Comment: @GuysWithDogs i've given you an alternative method just in case this one disappoints you at some stage, perhaps post my one liner in your code's comments above the .InvokeScript - although if you'd have to choose, I would use InvokeScript as a first plan, but the one i've provided also works with pre-.NET versions of the WB control. Hope it's all going well for ya mate, cheers, Erx.

Answer (score 2):

For those that may not be aware, you can also use .execScript in pre-.NET versions of WB control and current/.NET versions of WB control. You can also choose the language of the script you want to execute, ie: "JScript" or "VBScript". Here is the one liner:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow.execScript "alert('hello world');", "JScript"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that is probably the quickest way to do that, because the 'invokescript' simply needs to be given a name of a global function. So after pushing the functions down deeper into some structures, and to still be able to call them via InvokeScript in a "more pretty" way, you would have to, for example, write a single GLOBAL wrapper (a 'dispatcher' would be a better name), similar to the:

```
function callme(what, args) {
   var actualfunction = eval(what);   // or any other way to parse the 'what' and get a function
   return actualfunction(args);
}
```

and later call it:

- from JS:

  ```
  callme("$.city.venue.onVenueSelected", ..args..)
  ```

  (but I truly dont know why you could want to call it from JS :))
- and from CS:

  ```
  browser.InvokeScript("callme", new string[]{ "$.city.venue.onVenueSelected", ..args.. })
  ```

this way, I think you would be able to pass objects as function arguments directly, without stringifying them

..but from my experience, in >80% of the cases, you just need to pass some simple numbers and strings or setup flags, so all that hassle is usually just a code bloat