# How can I call a Function of an JavaScript Object with WPF?

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, browser

I have a WebBrowser instance in my WPF application (System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser). In the website I have the following JavaScript code.

```
// Javascript   
myNamespace = {};
myNamespace.helloJavaScriptMETHOD = function() { alert("Hello"); };

helloJavaScriptFUNCTION = function() { alert("Hello); };
```

I can call helloJavaScriptFUNCTION with

```
// C#
webBrowser.InvokeScript("helloJavaScriptFUNCTION");
```

How can I call helloJavaScriptMETHOD without changing the WebSite/JavaScript? I have tried the following WITHOUT success:

```
// C#
webBrowser.InvokeScript("myNamespace.helloJavaScriptMETHOD");
webBrowser.InvokeScript("(function(){ return myNamespace.helloJavaScriptMETHOD; })");
webBrowser.InvokeScript("myNamespace.helloJavaScriptMETHOD()");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be able to call a JavaScript method in a namespace directly but you can use `eval`. A similar technique was used to invoke JQuery. Look at [How to call a jQuery function from .NET WebBrowser control using InvokeScript()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188063/how-to-call-a-jquery-function-from-net-webbrowser-control-using-invokescript). It uses the wrong control but the technique may work here.