# WebBrowser control not responding to InvokeMember("click")

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control

After spending 5 days of my life, I'm about to give up on this, but am consulting the experts once before that.

I have a WebBrowser control that loads a webpage and I programmatically scrape its contents. Clicking a particular menu item in the page brings up File Open dialog when done in IE (or any other browser). But clicking the same button in WebBrowser control using `InvokeMember()` apparently doesn't do anything no matter what. I've gone through several SO questions such as [Setting Browser Features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call) to make sure my control behaves exactly like IE, but that hasn't succeeded.

I went as far as inspecting the actual javascript function that the button is executing behind the scene and calling it manually using `HtmlDocument.InvokeScript()` but couldn't do that because the underlying function takes an argument of `MouseEvent` type (the click event actually) and I'm not sure how can I create that object in C#.

Another approach was to set focus to that particular button and then try `SendKeys`, but that won't work because the WebBrowser control is not visible. It is just an in-memory instance. To be more specific, the WebBrowser

### EDIT

On a reader's request, here's the simple code that I'm using to find the element:

```
var MyButton = WB.Document.GetElementById("processfilelink");
```

`processfilelink` is an anchor tag (`<a href='#' ... >`) and I have confirmed that this element actually exists in the body of the document. The webpage uses jQuery's `delegate` feature to bind this anchor's `click` event to the target function. After locating the button, I simply call `InvokeMember()` like this:

```
MyButton.InvokeMember("click");
```

Note: I also see bindings for mousedown, mouseup and focus events in the page code. I expect all these events to automatically fire when one invokes `click`, but just to be sure I added `InvokeMember` calls for these events too. Results are no better.

Comment: To the close-voter, if THIS is off-topic, I wonder what in the world would be on-topic.

Comment: Sorry... was distracted for a second... Please provide code that you use to find element - and what element you actually find. Note that not everything is "clickable"... Otherwise it is not possible to suggest anything. Also does code works when you show the browser?

Comment: "A" should receive click... If you add your own click handler to that element via `InvokeScript` does it get called? Have you tried `InvokeScript` for something like `$("#InvokeScript").trigger("click")` (assuming you already have jQuery on page)? I believe that depending on how you make "WebBrowser control is not visible" it may not fire all loading events or lay out controls reasonably thus making elements hidden - check size/state of the document... You may need to use PhantomJS if you want headless browser.

Comment: Do you mean `$("#processfilelink").trigger("click")`? (i m not too familiar with jQuery, but `InvokeScript` is a .net thing).

Comment: Yes, if page HTML page already uses jQuery you can [call `eval` with script as argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188063/how-to-call-a-jquery-function-from-net-webbrowser-control-using-invokescript) to execute any script from C# code like `doc.InvokeScript("eval", "$(\"#processfilelink\").trigger(\"click\")")`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: OK. `InvokeScript("alert", new object[] {"abc"});` works and brings up a popup, but `trigger("click")` thing u mentioned above doesn't appear to do anything. So let's try to call the underlying function directly just like `alert`. The js function is named `pf` and takes two arguments `n` and `t`. I used Chrome to debug the function. The value of `t` is `false`, whereas the value of `n` is `MouseEvent`. Can I create this argument in C# and pass it directly?

Comment: I don't think you can create/pass MouseEvent from C#. Try to write JavaScript code that does what you want and than `eval` it from C# with `InvokeScript("eval",...)`. Note that most event listeners actually don't care about most/all properties of event object - so you may be able to construct something simple that complete event...

Comment: @dotNET, load this page in full IE browser, use F12 Tools to debug it and execute `button.click()` in JavaScript console. Does it work as expected this way?

Comment: @Noseratio: Wow, now that's interesting. It doesn't work! But clicking on the item by hand does work flawlessly. What's going on here?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: OK. That works. I mean I'm able to construct an event object in JS and pass it to my function, but now it brings up `object doesn't support this action` error with line 1, char 1.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments:

> ... load this page in full IE browser, use F12 Tools to debug it and
>   execute button.click() in JavaScript console. Does it work as expected
>   this way?

So, you've tried that, and the result is:

> ... now that's interesting. It doesn't work! But clicking on the item
>   by hand does work flawlessly. What's going on here?

I suspected that as `MyButton.InvokeMember("click")` doesn't work. Apparently, the page handles this click by other means than via `onclick` event. Most likely, it uses `onmousedown` or `onmouseup` events. Study the page's scripting logic to verify if that's the case, use F12 debugger and put some break points.

**Updated**, if it turns out the page indeed uses `onmousedown`/`onmouseup`, you'd need to make your `WebBrowser` visible and automate it by posting `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication_22979038
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.webBrowser.DocumentText = "<a id='goLink' href='javascript:alert(\"Hello!\"),undefined'>Go</a><script></script>";

            this.webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
        }

        void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = this.webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("goLink");
            element.Focus();
            var hwnd = GetFocus();
            if (!IsChild(this.webBrowser.Handle, hwnd))
                throw new ApplicationException("Unexpected focused window.");

            var rect = GetElementRect(element);
            IntPtr wParam = (IntPtr)MK_LBUTTON;
            IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)(rect.Left | rect.Top << 16);
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, wParam, lParam);
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, wParam, lParam);
        }

        // get the element rect in window client area coordinates
        static Rectangle GetElementRect(HtmlElement element)
        {
            var rect = element.OffsetRectangle;
            int left = 0, top = 0;
            var parent = element;
            while (true)
            {
                parent = parent.OffsetParent;
                if (parent == null)
                    return new Rectangle(rect.X + left, rect.Y + top, rect.Width, rect.Height);
                var parentRect = parent.OffsetRectangle;
                left += parentRect.Left;
                top += parentRect.Top;
            }
        }

        // interop

        const int MK_LBUTTON = 0x0001;
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);

        [DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr GetFocus();

        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool IsChild(IntPtr hWndParent, IntPtr hWnd);
    }
}
```