# Controlling a C# WebBrowser object in code to push a button which is initially disabled?

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, forms

I'm loading a web page into a `WebBrowser` object, and part of the web page has an HTML `Form` with 3 attributes, namely two `Select` attributes and one `Input` attribute of type `Submit`. The two `Select` attributes present different lists of choices, and having made a choice one presses the button that corresponds to the `Input` attribute which causes data to be loaded.  When the program is running and the `WebBrowser` object is visible, I can manually use the mouse and the web page loads the data correctly, exactly as though it was running in a browser like e.g. Chrome.  However, when I try to write C# to control the `WebBrowser` object, it doesn't work.

When the web page is first loaded, the `Input` attribute on the form is greyed out.  However, using the mouse to make a choice in either of the two `Select` attributes causes the `Input` attribute to be enabled and it changes colour to green.  The C# code I have to make a selection doesn't replicate that behaviour, because the `Input` attribute doesn't get enabled as a result of the code (below) which does the selection. It's not clear to me where the code which causes the `Input` attribute to be enabled is located, but I've been hoping that I don't need to work that out.

The HTML code for the form is as follows:

```
<form method="get" id="filter-nav">  
    <fieldset> 
        <label for="group-drop-down">Show me:</label> 
        <select id="drop-down-1" name="filter"> 
            <option value="">drop-down-1-heading</option>
            <optgroup label="optgroup-1-label" id="optgroup-1" >  
                <option value="optgroup-1-choice-1"  > Choice-1 </option> 
                <option value="optgroup-1-choice-2"  > Choice-2 </option>   
            </optgroup> 
            <optgroup label="optgroup-2-label" id="optgroup-2" > 
                <option value="optgroup-2-choice-3"  > Choice-3 </option> 
                <option value="optgroup-2-choice-4"  > Choice-4 </option>   
            </optgroup> 
        </select>
        <span>OR</span>  
        <select id=""drop-down-2" name="filter"> 
            <option value="">drop-down-2-heading</option> 
            <optgroup label="optgroup-3-label" id="optgroup-3" >  
                <option value="optgroup-3-choice-5"  > Choice-5 </option> 
                <option value="optgroup-3-choice-6"  > Choice-6 </option>   
            </optgroup> 
            <optgroup label="optgroup-4-label" id="optgroup-4" > 
                <option value="optgroup-4-choice-7"  > Choice-7 </option> 
                <option value="optgroup-4-choice-8"  > Choice-8 </option>   
            </optgroup> 
        </select>
        <input id="filter-nav-submit" type="submit" value="Update" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and the C# code that I've been using to try and control it is the LoadData() method of the following class

```
private class WebBrowserHelper {
    WebBrowser wb;

    public void LoadData() {
        HtmlElement select1 = getElement("select", "drop-down-1");
        select1.Focus();
        Application.DoEvents();
        select1.SetAttribute("Value", "optgroup-1-choice-2");
        Application.DoEvents();
        select1.InvokeMember("change");
        Application.DoEvents();

        // at this point, the select1 dropdown shows the right value
        // but the button corresponding to the input attribute is still greyed out

    }
    public HtmlElement getElement(string tagName, string IdName) {
        HtmlElementCollection theElementCollection = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName(tagName);
        foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection) {
            object id = curElement.GetAttribute("id");
            if (id != null && id.Equals(IdName)) return curElement;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Opinion: I would move this work to the web page and just send it in the URL to load, for example: http://mypage.html?OptGroup=2 etc.. We have something similar running in production and it's been working pretty good.

Comment: @EricScherrer thanks for reading my query.  However, if I understand you correctly, you're suggesting that I alter the web page that I'm loading into the `WebBrowser` object.  Unfortunately I can't do that because it's not a web page that I control.

Comment: Bummer. I am not too knowledgeable on what your trying to do but my only other suggestion would be giving the System.Windows.Automation library a try and screen scrape it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might with `Application.DoEvents` (which BTW is an evil even for UI automation). A single iteration of the message loop pump that it does may just be not enough. Ideally, you should be using `async/await` and some asynchronous delay:

```
public async Task LoadDataAsync() {
    HtmlElement select1 = getElement("select", "drop-down-1");
    select1.Focus();
    await Task.Delay(200);
    select1.SetAttribute("Value", "optgroup-1-choice-2");
    await Task.Delay(200);
    select1.InvokeMember("change");
    await Task.Delay(200);

    // ...
}
```

However, if you take this road, the code has to be async ["all the way down"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

If that doesn't help anyway, just try enabling the button manually:

```
HtmlElement button = getElement("input", "filter-nav-submit");
button.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, although neither of them worked.  Somehow, manually using the web page must invoke a change method on the `select` attribute which for some reason isn't getting invoked by my code.  And it must be doing more than enabling the button, because manually enabling and then calling `button.InvokeMember("Click")` doesn't cause the data to be loaded.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Stochastically, no problem. The page probably has some dynamic JavaScript logic, so it'd be hard to help any further without being able to repro.

Comment: (FYI, the web page that I'm looking at is http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/results, and the button name on the real page and my code here is the same.)

Comment: @Stochastically, this page is a not an easy one to automate via DOM, but you could simulate a mouse click, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22984360/1768303