# Reset Zoom in webBrowserControl

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, windows-phone-7.1, zooming

I have a `webBrowser Control` in my application. I navigate to a web page and zoom it using pinch zooming. Now on clicking of a button, I change the current webPage of the webBrowser control. The new webPage appears automatically zoomed in. How can I reset this zoom everytime on a new navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a post about your problem:
[WP7 WebBrowser control zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500062/wp7-webbrowser-control-zoom)

You have to manipulate the html of your page and reset the viewport.

Comment: If you can change the page, you can use the 'InvokeScript' method. otherwise, you can use 'SaveToString' to get the html, modify it and inject it in your webbrowser.