# How do resize a Webbrowser in Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I just try to simulate a resizing event of a webbrowser. It's because some user who are older and are not able to read that good see the conten in a bigger size. Following a simple version of the code:

```
<Viewbox x:Name="BrowserView" Stretch="None" >
   <phone:WebBrowser Source="www.google.ch" x:Name="Minibrowser" IsScriptEnabled="True" height="644" Width="462"  >

            </phone:WebBrowser>
</Viewbox>
  <Button  Content="Resize" Click="Resize" />
```

Xaml.Code

And in the underlying code file a method which just resizes the webbrowser:

```
private void Resize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Minibrowser.Width = 800;
     Minibrowser.Height = 1400;}
```

What happens is that the browser is resized. However it's not possible to scroll over the whole content because the webbrowser size is now bigger than the viewbox and screen as well.

Thanks a lot for help and I'm open to listen to other solutions

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post about managing the [browser-viewport](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/archive/2011/01/21/managing-the-browser-viewport-in-windows-phone-7.aspx) and [WP7 WebBrowser control zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500062/wp7-webbrowser-control-zoom).

Plus, you could also look for "accessibility"...